# What is the difference between these three tests?

Tags: java, testing, gradle, intellij-idea, cucumber

what is the difference between these there options, the RunTest.java in the picture below (left), the verification test in the picture below (right), and the command: `gradle clean test`

[image]

Only the vericifation-test work in my project (but it doesn't write anything in the databases-.-), and I dont know why...

I hope someone can give me a helpful hint :)

Comment: The left one runs one specific class, the right one starts a gradle job with the ``test`` goal and ``grade clean test`` manually runs the grade job without involving the IDE. There shouldn't be any differences in runnning these except for a possible different environment which we can't see here.

Comment: Hmm okay, but why only the right one works in my project correct?:(

Comment: It's possible the grade verification test goal isnt finding the `RunTest` if it's not located in the "tests" java folder?

Comment: It is in the test--java folder... It worked the first time, but after I integrated  a database, only the verfication-test work :/